# Wordcloud from dictionary with normalized frequencies

Tags: python, word-cloud

I have a dictionary that contains words as keys and *relative* frequencies as values and looks like this:
`{'new': 0.018277079025640526, 'house': 0.01629428520190653,..., 'need': 0.008237148655962019}` and I need to generate a word-cloud.
I tried using WordCloud for the purpose:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

cloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                  background_color='white',
                  width=2500,
                  height=1800,
                  max_words=20,
                  colormap='tab10',
                  color_func=lambda *args, **kwargs: cols[i],
                  prefer_horizontal=1.0)

cloud.generate_from_frequencies(my_dictionary, max_font_size=300)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py", line 533, in generate_from_frequencies
    font_path=self.font_path))
  File "<input>", line 7, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range`
```

I don't understand why I get this error, is it because I am using relative frequencies? (note: I do not have the total number of words, so I cannot transform the relative frequencies to number of occurrences of each word).

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Very useful, thanks.